# Identification of HDD by SATA port number

Tags: hard-drive, sata

How do I find out which motherboard SATA port number is an HDD connected to?

We want to build a hdd copy software based on physical identification of SATA.

Answer (score 16):

lsscsi --verbose will provide output similar to this:

```
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      TOSHIBA THNSNH12 HTRA  /dev/sda 
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0]
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD2003FZEX-0 01.0  /dev/sdb 
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/1:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0]
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD3001FAEX-0 01.0  /dev/sdc 
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/2:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0]
[3:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  Optiarc  DVD RW AD-7280S  1.01  /dev/sr0 
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/3:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata4/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0]
```

which provides the **`ataN`** port which can matchup with information found in the syslog. Useful if you are trying to determine where an error is coming from .

**Edit: If `which lsscsi` provides no output you need to install it:**

```
sudo apt-get install lsscsi
```

**Further Edit:**

This probably goes without saying, but of course you can filter the output with `grep` to locate what you are interested in for instance if you find an error like `ata4: status: { DRDY ERR }` you could simple issue the command

> lsscsi --verbose | grep -P1 -A1 ata4
>   Which would produce output like this:

```
[3:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  Optiarc  DVD RW AD-7280S  1.01  /dev/sr0 
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/3:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata4/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0]
```

Which would indicate that the device (Optiarc  DVD RW AD-7280S on ata4) wasn't ready when called upon.

This should be enough information to allow you to locate the troubled device.

Answer (score 11):

`sudo lshw -c storage -c disk` gives you a lot of info regarding your hard-drives. Eg:

```
 *-scsi:1
      physical id: 2
      logical name: scsi2
      capabilities: emulated
    *-disk
         description: ATA Disk
         product: ST31000524AS
         vendor: Seagate
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdb
         version: JC4B
         serial: 5VPDESM5
         size: 931GiB (1TB)
         capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
         configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=d6e747d2-3e9c-47c2-865b-44f8d7cc5808 sectorsize=512
       *-volume
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
            logical name: /dev/sdb1
            logical name: /mnt/hdd0
            version: 1.0
            serial: 2de34713-f0ee-4a12-9214-21a5431a7b7b
            size: 931GiB
            capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2013-07-20 14:14:09 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/mnt/hdd0 modified=2013-08-29 21:29:24 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2013-08-29 21:29:24 state=mounted
```

I suspect `physical id` gives you the physical port the HDD is connected to (2 in this case).

Comment: I have SATA ports numbered: 0,1,2,3. lshw reports physical id's: 5,6,7,8. This answer does not seem to be correct.

Comment: I think "*-scsi:1" of the lshw report is referring to SATA port 1.

Comment: didn't work for me. The SATA port was 7, lshw physical id was 9. Use with caution!

Comment: @Preexo Try `lsscsi --verbose`

Comment: The field you are looking for is `bus info`. Since extensive anwer editing [is discouraged](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/edit), I've split that off into a [separate answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1100639/101406) with a more in-depth example.

Answer (score 5):

## sudo apt-get install lsscsi

```
tech@tech:~$ lsscsi
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      SAMSUNG HD040GJ/ ZG10  /dev/sda
[3:0:1:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD3200AAJS-0 03.0  /dev/sdb
[4:0:0:0]    disk    Generic- Compact Flash    1.00  /dev/sdc
[4:0:0:1]    disk    Generic- SM/xD-Picture    1.00  /dev/sdd
[4:0:0:2]    disk    Generic- SD/MMC           1.00  /dev/sde
[4:0:0:3]    disk    Generic- MS/MS-Pro/HG     1.00  /dev/sdf
```

this utility will give you ATA port 0 to 3.

Comment: Can I know if I have a Gigabyte motherboard? If I use that command, will it damage my hardware? Because the way you wrote your answer sounds as if I would damage my hardware if I try it right now ;)

Comment: It works pefectly fine on intel motherboards.

Comment: works on Supermicro boards, too.

Comment: @Rahim where is 0-3 in your sample output? I see 2,3,4

Answer (score 1):

`sudo lshw -c storage -c disk` gives you a lot of info regarding your hard-drives.

The `bus info` fields give you the physical port each HDD/SSD is connected to (ports 0 and 2 in this case).
Note that the number may differ if your system has multiple SATA controllers (on-board or via extension cards).

For example:

```
  *-scsi:0
       physical id: 1
       logical name: scsi0
       capabilities: emulated
     *-disk
          description: ATA Disk
          product: Samsung SSD 840
          physical id: 0.0.0
          bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sda
          version: BB6Q
          serial: S1DBNSAF791657P
          size: 232GiB (250GB)
          capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
          configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=d6cfe005
  *-scsi:1
       physical id: 2
       logical name: scsi2
       capabilities: emulated
     *-disk
          description: ATA Disk
          product: CT500MX500SSD1
          physical id: 0.0.0
          bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sdb
          version: 010
          serial: 1810E132AC1E
          size: 465GiB (500GB)
          capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
          configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=4096 signature=0007569c
```

Comment: (Extending [@Cubiq's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/339243/101406) beyond the scope of editing, therefore as a separate answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late for this question, but 10 years later I had the same need:

I always have an issue to find out quickly which disk is which port on my desktop. So, given I have labeled cables on disk side (they are very difficult to follow from motherboard), I wrote a quick and dirty script, which uses `/dev/disk/by-path` information :

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# output sata/disk relationship.

find /dev/disk/by-path/ -regex '^.*ata-[0-9]+$' -print |
    while read -r file; do
        sata=$(echo "$file" | sed -n 's|.*\(ata\)-\([0-9]*\).*|s\1\2|p')
        drive=$(readlink -f "$file")
        printf "%s %s \n" "$sata" "${drive##*/}"
    done | sort
exit 0
```

Output example:

```
$ sata2disk.sh 
sata1 sda 
sata2 sdb
```