# Is there a way to check for sure what version of SATA on my laptop?

Tags: sata

I'm using a 8 years old laptop, lenovo G480.. according to the spec on the internet, it has SATA 300 interface, which should be SATA 2 or SATA 3 gb/s

However when I check in terminal with

> sudo dmesg | grep -i sata | grep 'link up'
>
> sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep SATA

it display SATA 3.0, 6 gb/s

so I'm wondering if it's detecting my SSD which is ADATA SU650 or do my laptop really do have SATA 3 or SATA 6gb/s interface.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the system capability with

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i sata | grep -i ahci
```

and the current drive connection with

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i sata | grep 'link up'
```

**Related**:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/417857/how-to-find-sata-controller-version-on-ubuntu-laptop-do-i-have-sata-1-2-or-3
2. [Identification of HDD by SATA port number](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339232/identification-of-hdd-by-sata-port-number)
3. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-to-find-sata-harddisk-link-speed/
4. [How to check/enable the full speed of SATA drive/port?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048882/how-to-check-enable-the-full-speed-of-sata-drive-port)